# How can my startup script put messages that appear during the boot screen and in dmesg?

Tags: boot, output

I need to see exactly when my script starts, and how long it takes for various components to execute. I tried `logger` but it doesn't work for this purpose.

Comment: This does not appear to be specific to the Raspberry Pi. It seems to be a general Linux question.

Comment: Well, it's a Debian question, since not all Linux systems have the same start up mechanism.